# glassfish 5 JSF2.2 & CDI deployment failure

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish

I tried searching around for similar errors, but I couldn't find anything relevent... So I turn to the stack community to help me

I trying to deploy my application on glassfish 5. But when I run my application on my server I get this error :

```
 org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:org.jboss.weldx.transaction.UserTransaction$$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$ cannot be cast to org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyObject
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:239)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

the following code correspond at my pom.xml :

```
  <!-- Implementation JEE7 (JSF2, JPA2, EJB3.1, Servlet3, JTA, Bean Validation, 
        etc) -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces (framework d'IHM) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ThÃ¨me graphique de Primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.theme.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J (Interface de logging) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LogBack (Implementation de logging) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0-GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JODA Time (Librairie de gestion de date). Les API Date et Calendar 
        de java sont deprecated -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${jodatime.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Omnifaces (framework utilitaire pour JSF) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>${omniface.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Driver Oracle -->
    <!-- Aucun repository public pour rÃ©cupÃ©rer le driver. Il faut le rÃ©cupÃ©rer 
        sur le site oracle et jouer la commande suivante -->
    <!-- mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 
        -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgeneratePom=true -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.ojdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementation de reference de l'API BeanValidation (JSR 303) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache POI (framework de manipulation de fichiers Microsoft Office, 
        dont Excel) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>${ooxml.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- IText pour l'Ã©dition PDF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have already corrected several errors by following the answers of these different links by adapting to my case :
[JSF/Bean #{} not rendered/parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454432/jsf-bean-not-rendered-parsed)

[How to install and use CDI on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat)

[Prevent Glassfish from using its own versions of libraries instead of those in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403919/prevent-glassfish-from-using-its-own-versions-of-libraries-instead-of-those-in-a)

thanks for all help!!

-------------- EDIT ---------------

here is the list of dependency versions that I'm using

```
    <javaee-web-api.version>8.0</javaee-web-api.version>
    <primefaces.version>6.2</primefaces.version>
    <primefaces.theme.version>1.0.10</primefaces.theme.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <yuicompressor.version>1.5.1</yuicompressor.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <glassfish.embedded.version>5.0</glassfish.embedded.version>
    <oracle.ojdbc.version>12.1.0.2</oracle.ojdbc.version>
    <omniface.version>2.0</omniface.version>
    <jodatime.version>2.7</jodatime.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.18.1</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <jmockit.version>1.18</jmockit.version>
    <poi.version>3.12</poi.version>
    <itext.version>2.1.7</itext.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco.version>
    <ooxml.version>1.1</ooxml.version>
```

Comment: What versions of **JDK** and **javaee-web-api** are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 8. Thank's for your help

Comment: Let me clarify my questions: [1] What version of **JDK** (Java) are you using? [2] What version of **javaee-web-api** are you using?

Comment: Excuse me I have not been clear. I'm using the version 8 for both. More precisely for JDK I'm using the version 1.8.0_171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my issu in this way :

1. delete the following dependency : org.jboss.weld.servlet
2. right click on your project **Preferences** --> **Project Facets** --> click on **runtimes** then **check** Glassfish 5.